# jQuery's slideUp/slideDown instant without animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `div` that I want to perform `slideUp`/`slideDown` on.

The only problem is that there is no animation. it just hides/shows the element.

The content is dynamically loaded via ajax.

```
$('body').on("change", ".attendingaction", function(e){
    // Assign a reference
    var self = $(this);
    var menu_list = self.closest(".results-item").find(".menus");

    if(self.val() == "Yes")
        menu_list.slideDown(400);
    else{
        menu_list.slideUp(50, function(){
            $(this).find(".menuitem").removeProp("checked");
        });
    }
});
```

Even more bizarre, it works if the `display` is "block". but in this case, it sets it to "table-cell" after performing `slideDown()`.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: can  u create a fiddle please

Comment: fiddle or pen please?